# function exits when passing data to aws cognito after reading file from s3 in aws lambda in nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

i am new to this , i am having problem , i have to create  almost 200 users in cognito after reading data from csv file which is located in S3 bucket
the problem is , if a user already exists in Cognito , my code stop executing and give me an error "An account with the given email already exists." is there a way that i can pass the whole data. if there is user already in the cognito with the same email, it skips that user and checks for the new user data , and at the end which users are already exists in cognito  .this the function to create user in cognito
here is the function for creating the cognito user

```
       function RegisterUser(data2) {
console.log(data2[1])

for(let i=0;i<=data2.length;i++){
     var attributeList = [];
     var cognitoUser;
    attributeList.push(new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute({ Name: "name", Value: data2[i][0]}));
    attributeList.push(new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute({ Name: "email", Value: data2[i][1] }));
    
    try{
      
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    userPool.signUp(data2[i][1], data2[i][2], attributeList, null, (err, result) => {
      
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        reject(err);
        return;
        
      }
      cognitoUser = result.user;
      resolve(cognitoUser);
    });
  });
      
    }catch(err){
      
      return{
        
        success:false,
        message:err
        
      }
      
    }

 
}
}
```

here is the lambda handler

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {

    // Converted it to async/await syntax just to simplify.
    const data = await S3.getObject({Bucket: 'user-data-file', Key: 'SampleCSVFile_2kb.csv'}).promise();
    var data1 = Buffer.from(data.Body).toString();

  var   data2 = data1.split("\r\n"); // SPLIT ROWS
for (let i in data2) { // SPLIT COLUMNS

  data2[i] = data2[i].split(",");
}

const userPoolResponse = await RegisterUser(data2);
  }

  catch (err) {
    return {
      statusCode: err.statusCode || 400,
      body: err.message || JSON.stringify(err.message)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search brought this up: [How to check Email Already exists in AWS Cognito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51083100/how-to-check-email-already-exists-in-aws-cognito)

Which sure thats Front end but your use case seem to be a quick once in a while run script, not a regular use User System - in which case, this is basic programing 101 to solve. You put another try catch around your call to register the user. You check the exception thrown, and if its 'already registered' you pass and continue in the loop without interruption. The above link can give you some idea of what to look for to determine if it is that exception or not.