# Check if a username exists in Cognito User pool

Tags: authentication, amazon-cognito

I want my authentication flow to meet these scenarios: check if a username exists. If it exists, then navigate to sign-in screen. Otherwise navigate to sign-up screen.
I cannot find documentation on how to check if a username exists in AWS Cognito.

Comment: We do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72318922/470749

Answer (score 2):

You can use [adminGetUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html) to pass the username and user pool id. If the user exists you will get a 200 success response. Just put an if condition based on the response.

Comment: How would you use adminGetUser() in Flutter? Been trying `Amplify.Auth.adminGetUser()` but it doesnt seem to exist